# bash: :command not found Cloud9 Enviroment

Tags: ruby, bash, cloud9-ide

This is my first Ruby development, I'm following through a book thats teaching me to build a Pinterest clone. Everything was working correctly until I logged into the environment today to pick up where I left off. When I try and run the project, or boot up the server, I'm getting this error.

```
bash: :command not found
```

It was working correctly last night when I closed the environment, and I havn't been able to find any information online as to how to fix the problem. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks. Let me know if you need additional code supplied.

Comment: 1) Check the contents of `PATH` environment variable by calling `echo $PATH`. 2) What do you get by running `type bash` or `which bash` ?

Comment: here are the results of the echo $PATH command

Comment: /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/mnt/shared/bin:/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/.bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/mnt/shared/sbin:/opt/gitl:/opt/go/bin:/mnt/shared/c9/app.nw/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin

Comment: type bash returns-----bash is /bin/bash

Comment: it's not a PATH problem.

Comment: There doesn't look like there is a bash file in my /bin. Just bundle-rails-rake-spring. Do I need to add a bash file?

Comment: I'm not used to cloud environments. List the contents of your `/bin` path. What do you get from `echo $SHELL` ?

Comment: echo $SHELL returns /bin/bash------the contents of my bin path are as follows---/bin/bundle, /bin/rails, /bin/rake, /bin/spring

Comment: Reboot/restart your cloud environment. It's not normal what you see there.

Comment: I just rebooted, and I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: I ran out of ideas :( If you pay money for those cloud services, contact your provider. Otherwise, you'd better get a local linux machine :)

Comment: Can you confirm that you have `.profile` and `.bashrc` in `/home/ubuntu`?  They should both be timestamped from before your issue started (I use Cloud9 and mine are from 11/2014).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your runner is set to `Ruby on Rails` and not `Shell`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Not sure what else to say here. This is the answer. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Rails only via Bundler, then rails will only be accessible if you run bundle exec rails.

A "naked" rails command will only exist if you gem install rails directly without Bundler.