# bash: :command not found on Cloud9 not resolving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, cloud9-ide

When I try and run the project, or boot up the server, I'm getting this error.

**bash: :command not found**

Already tried the solution mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740951/bash-command-not-found-cloud9-enviroment). But I am still having this issue. Don't have enough reputation to post a comment there hence the repeat question. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably best to email support@c9.io about this

Comment: Thanks Brady. I will send a note to support.